# Connect a signalR client to an external console server

Tags: c#, ip, client-server, signalr, external

I could establish a comunication between a signal R client and a console made from C# as the server which listens to a port. That comunicatios worked fine being on the local host. It also worked out using two computers in the same LAN. One working as a server and the other as the client.

The problem starts when I want to run my program from C# in an external server, specifically in an Amazon server that I hired. In this case the server runs fine, but the clients can´t access it.

I think that my problem can be that the server provides a public IP (54.xxx.xxx.xxx) and a private IP (172.xxx.xxx.xxx). In my progam I reference the public IP.

I belive it can be the problem, but I dont know how to comunicate whit that private IP. I´ll leave de code below. Thank you for the help.

Client:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    What's your name?: <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />


    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="http://54.xxx.xxx.xxx:9988/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $.connection.hub.url = "http://54.xxx.xxx.xxx:9988/signalR";

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.addMessage = function (text) {
                alert(text);
            };

            // Start the connection.

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                })
            });


        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server:

```
namespace SignalRSelfHost {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string url="http://*:9988";
            using(WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub {
        public void Send(string name) {
            Clients.All.addMessage("Hi "+ name+"!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the port is open - it might be a firewall that blocks requests.

Comment: i tried turning off the firewall and it didnt work.